# Hadoop Pseudo-Distributed Task failed

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

For some strange reasons I get the below exception when i try to run wordcount example in Pseudo-Distributed mode. **It says exit with status -1**

Enviornment: Cygwin

```
    java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of -1.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? If you consult the actual task log you should be able to see what the actual exception was. This is just a more general high level exception telling you the Task exited in an unexpected way. This probably is some exception occuring in the Task execution.

Comment: Could you please share you TT logs?